# Cython write a python wrapper to third-party shared library

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, cython

I need help in writing a wrapper to call some functions and get JSON responce (a unicode string) from a third-party shared library. The library's headers file is shown below:

```
#include <string>
#include <ExportLib.h>
// some code ignored here
typedef std::string UString;
using namespace std;
namespace ns1{
class DLL_PUBLIC S_API {
public:
static UString function1();
static UString function2();
// some code ignored here
};
}
```

The problem is I'm not so good in C/C++, so I have no idea what to do with Cython. I would be very grateful if someone would point me in right direction. I wrote a .pyx file like so:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
cdef extern from "libName.h" namespace "ns1":
     cdef cppclass S_API:
          string function1;
          string function2;
```

This compiles fine and I do get a .so file, which I can import in Pyhton. But I am still unable to access function1() or any other function inside the module.

Comment: I am not using c++ with cython (only C) but your definitions `string function1` are for variables and not for methods. see http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html for the syntax. Also, with the steps you have given, the class methods would be available from the cython file and not python directly, you'd have to write a wrapper.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, thanks for the hint. I will try and let you know.